# How to express an interconnected type hierarchy in Typescrpt

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to figure out how to best express a type dependency. I'm working on a game with the following hierarchy:

```
enum Factions {
  Government,
  Intelligentsia
}

enum GovernmentTypes {
  Liberal,
  Autocratic,
  Neutral
}

enum IntelligentsiaTypes {
  Scientific,
  Religious,
  Neutral
}

interface Building {
  name: string,
  faction: Factions,
  subtype: ?--HOW-TO-EXPRESS-THIS-TYPE--?
}
```

I want it so that when a Building's faction is:

- Government - subtype is limited to GovernmentTypes
- Intelligentsia- subtype is limited to IntelligentsiaTypes

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to express is the relationship between `Factions` and `***Types`.

I have captured that relationship in `Factions` object type.

Following should add constraint the way you are expecting:

```js
enum GovernmentTypes {
  Liberal,
  Autocratic,
  Neutral
}

enum IntelligentsiaTypes {
  Scientific,
  Religious,
  Neutral
}

type Factions = {
  Government: GovernmentTypes
  Intelligentsia: IntelligentsiaTypes
}

interface Building<T extends keyof Factions> {
  name: string
  faction: T
  subtype: Factions[T]
}

const factions1: Building<'Government'> = {
  name: 'Asd',
  faction: 'Government',
  subtype: GovernmentTypes.Autocratic
} //  compiles

const factions0: Building<'Government'> = {
  name: 'Asd',
  faction: 'Government',
  subtype: IntelligentsiaTypes.Neutral
} // does not compile
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! An additional question: when I now try to use an enum as the keys for the mapping and make a class extending the Building interface. I need to cast the value of faction as const, otherwise I get ` Type 'FACTIONS' is not assignable to type 'FACTIONS.GOVERNMENT'`. Am I missing someting, or this the way to do it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/chjme - on line 29 it works if I cast it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you really have to use enum for Factions, if you just use union type, then you ll not need to do that. Anyway union types are preferred over enums in general, quick google search should give you reasoning!

Answer (score 0):

Use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in interface definition, ie

```
interface Building<T> {
  name: string,
  faction: Factions,
  subtype: T
}

// usage
const building: Building<GovernmentTypes>
```

Comment: This doesn't enforce the faction and the subtype being interconnected in the right way. i.e. I don't want to be able to set the faction to "Government", but have the subtype for "Intelligentsia"

Comment: Have you read this article @debel https://medium.com/@KevinBGreene/typescript-enums-and-polymorphism-with-type-matching-fc3dc74b031c ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it help with the my problem, which is that I have 2 enums that are logically hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Factions {
  Government,
  Intelligentsia
}

enum GovernmentTypes {
  Liberal,
  Autocratic,
  Neutral
}

enum IntelligentsiaTypes {
  Scientific,
  Religious,
  Neutral
}

interface Building<T> {
  name: string,
  faction: Factions,
  subtype: T
}

export class GovermentBuilding implements Building<GovernmentTypes> {
    name = "name1";
    faction = Factions.Government;
    subtype = GovernmentTypes.Neutral;

    constructor(subtype: GovernmentTypes) {
        this.subtype = subtype;
    }
}

export class IntelligentsiaBuilding implements Building<IntelligentsiaTypes> {
    name = "name1";
    faction = Factions.Intelligentsia;
    subtype = IntelligentsiaTypes.Neutral;

    constructor(subtype: IntelligentsiaTypes) {
        this.subtype = subtype;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```faction = Factions.Government; subtype = IntelligentsiaTypes.Neutral;``` this is the exact situation I want to avoid

Comment: I don't understand - do you want multiple subtypes on an implementation of Building?

Comment: I want the subtype property to be type-checked according to the faction of the building.

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve that with inheritance alone

Comment: I'm learning the type system and there are many ways to express many types, but I just can't find the right way to express this. It doesn't need to be inheritance as long as it's statically type checked.

Comment: See my update - I don't think you can make it more generic than that